# Explanation of generator.close() with exception handling

Tags: python, generator

I am reading the python doc https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html about `generator.close()`.

My translation of the documentation is:

##generator.close()

Raises a `GeneratorExit` at the point where the generator function was paused.

1. If the generator function then exits gracefully :

1.1 is already closed,
1.2 or raises `GeneratorExit` (by not catching the exception),

`close` returns to its caller.

2. If the generator yields a value, a `RuntimeError` is raised.
3. If the generator raises any other exception, it is propagated to the caller.

`close()` does nothing if the generator has already exited due to an exception or normal exit.

---

I don't understand how the `close()` behavior corresponds to the documentation.

```
>>> def echo(value=None):
...     print("Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time.")
...     try:
...         while True:
...             try:
...                 value = (yield value)
...             except Exception as e:
...                 value = e
...     finally:
...         print("Don't forget to clean up when 'close()' is called.")
...
>>> generator = echo(1)
>>> next(generator)
Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time.
>>> generator.close()
Don't forget to clean up when 'close()' is called.
```

Which rule applies to `generator.close()` ? I am confused.

My understanding:

1. `generator.close()` raise a `GeneratorExit` exception
2. `GeneratorExit` is catched by `except Exception as e:` and loop continues
3. `value = (yield value)` executes
4. according to rule **2** above, a `RuntimeError` will be raised.

But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Please tell me what's going on inside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GeneratorExit` does not inherit from `Exception`, but from the more fundamental `BaseException`. Thus, it is not caught by your `except Exception` block.

So your assumption 2 is wrong. The generator exits gracefully via case 1.3, since `GeneratorExit` is not stopped.

1. The `GeneratorExit` is thrown at `(yield value)`.
2. The `try: except Exception as e:` checks whether the current exception is subclass of `Exception`. Since this is not the case, it unwinds.
3. The `while True:` unwinds due the current exception.
4. The `try: finally:` unwinds, running its `finally:` block. This causes the message to be displayed.
5. The generator exits with the current exception, i.e. `GeneratorExit`.
6. `generator.close` detects and suppresses `GeneratorExit`.

Comment: What does "exits gracefully" mean?

Comment: That means it exits without error, as opposed to exiting ungracefully by internally encountering an error (case 3) or failing to exit promptly (case 2).

Comment: As you've written in the question, if the Generator does raise or not stop ``GeneratorExit``, that's case 1.1. and ``.close()`` just returns.

Comment: Ah I see. I mistakenly classified `exits gracefully`, `is already closed,` and `or raises GeneratorExit (by not catching the exception),` into 3 cases, which is not true. Now I've corrected it in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What is _"the point where the generator function was paused"_ for a generator that has never been started with `next( )`? As you explain it is the `yield value` statement in the example above. Why is this the case? Why is it not before?

Comment: @kingusiu If the generator has never been started, ``.close`` will not run the generator at all. In any other case, the generator can *only* be paused by ``yield``, so that is where it may resume when calling ``.close`` on it. The code in the question is only half-complete, showing the behaviour after running the generator but not appropriate command to do so.